# Is this topology on $\mathbb{R}$ Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

Is the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ generated by the basis $(a,\infty)$ Hausdorff?

I do not think it is Hausdorff.

Proof: Taking unions of the sets of the form $(a,\infty)$ will always produce another set of the same form. So given $a < b$, whatever $2$ open sets you choose, they will never be disjoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the topology on R generated by the basis (a,∞ ) Hausdorff?

No, it isn't.

Let $a,b \in \mathbb R$, say $a<b$. Then every open set $C=(c,\infty)$ containing $a$ also contains $b$, since
$$a\in C=(c,\infty) \, \Rightarrow \, c<a \, \Rightarrow \, c<b \, \Rightarrow \, b\in C=(c,\infty)$$

Comment: So this will be an example of a space that is $\mathrm T_0$ but not $\mathrm T_1$ ?

Comment: Yes, this space is $\mathrm T_0$ but not $\mathrm T_1$.